# WinRt TextBlock with single space width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, whitespace, textblock

I'm trying to make a text on path element. To accomplish this I split original text to single characters and for each character create new TextBlock and count it's width after measurement. The problem is, that when a TextBlock contains only a single space it's width is 0, it seam's space is being trimmed.
How do I prevent trimming spaces? Or maybe there's a better suggestion?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking exactly, maybe share some of what you're trying, but maybe you're talking about `xml:space="preserve"` ?

Comment: As far as I googled, that doesn't work in winrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place a space on path - you don't really need to display a `TextBlock` there. If you want to measure how much space a space should use [sic] - you can compare the width of something like "aa" and "a a".

Comment: You can also check my code for [`CascadingTextBlock`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/CascadingTextBlock/CascadingTextBlock.xaml.cs) to see a few tricks...

Comment: Well, actually, you are right, I simply don't need to put anything there, but to skip some place, thanks!

Comment: @FilipSkakun +1 bravo sir.