# How to measure the width of whitespace in windows store?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, textblock

How can i measure the width of whitespace in winrt. 
I'm trying the below code for calculate the size,

For example,

```
var text = "    ";
TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
txtBlock.Text = text;
txtBlock.FontSize = 14;
...
txtBlock.Measure(size);
var actualWidth = txtBlock.ActualWidth;
```

But i'm getting width as 0. Please any one help me.

Comment: if you need to measure white spaces, it means that your entire approach to whatever you want to do is just simply WRONG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Measure()` then `Arrange()` and then ActualWidth and ActualHeight will be updated. This works for me.

Comment: ActualWidth will return 0.0 only all the time. I do Measure() and Arrange(). But its return 0.

Comment: I think this will work only with text like "aaaa". Check this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388136/winrt-textblock-with-single-space-width

Comment: Yes, if "aa" its works fine. But i need to calculate for whitespaces("    "). How can i do?